# Explaining a function from the JUNG tutorial, EdgePropertyDialog

Tags: java, oop, graph, interface, jung

I am trying to implement some graph traversal algorithms in java while also creating a visual interface for them. I am using the JUNG library and used as a begging reference for my project this tutorial: http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf

The classes used in the tutorial:http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/

The weird JDialog class: http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/MouseMenu/EdgePropertyDialog.java

I understood most of it except a weird, presumably auto-generated function: 
If someone could help me I would be very thankful. Thanks

```
private void initComponents() {
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    capFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    wtFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Edge Properties");
    jButton1.setText("OK");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            okButtonHandler(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Capacity:");

    jLabel2.setText("Weight:");

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                .add(jButton1)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(jLabel2))
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(capFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(wtFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(jLabel1)
                .add(capFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(jLabel2)
                .add(wtFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(jButton1))
    );
    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

Comment: That tutorial was written several years ago and has not been maintained, as far as I know.  I suggest using one of the JUNG samples as your starting point instead, and asking questions based on that.

Comment: thanks, but this is one of those samples

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  That tutorial was written by a member of the JUNG community (not the JUNG development team) and is not part of the JUNG distribution, which has its own samples and is at https://github.com/jrtom/jung.